# Pandas Categories find value bin

Tags: python, pandas

I want to discretize an array: I am using are `pandas.cut`

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
arr = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 , 7])
factor = pd.cut(arr, 2)
```

How I can get the factor bin for a arbitrary value (i.e. 2.5 is in the first bin)?
 Or are there better solutions (of course I can always do my own `for` loop...)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Save the bins and use pd.cut again:

```
factor, bins = pd.cut(arr, 2, retbins=True)
pd.cut([2.5], bins=bins)
Out: 
[(0.994, 4]]
Categories (2, object): [(0.994, 4] < (4, 7]]
```

Comment: Thanks. Just a more hint: is it possible to get the bin index too?

Comment: The returning object is a categorical Series and it has the `.codes` attribute. You can figure out the order with `pd.cut([2.5], bins=bins).codes` (if you pass a Series instead, you need to use `cat` accessor first (`ser.cat.codes`)).